# Test app with Android Dynamic Features on a remote device

Tags: android, deployment, apk, bundle, dep

I have an Android app under development which uses Dynamic Features. I know that apps with Dyn. Features should be build as a BUNDLE, but the probleme is that I need to deploy the app and all its features to a test device that is located in a remote office and that has a separate network (not bind-able to my Android Studio) in order to start testing and showing the app to the final customers before the final release. I have tried to build an APK, but the app crashes because it doesn't find the classes defined inside the Dynamic Features. It there a way to build an APK that contains all the feature and that can be installed on a clean device which is not bound to an Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is already in the Play Store, you could use [internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en-GB)? Then you would just share a link to your clients and they'd be able to download the app from Play.

If you really need to share an APK, you can use [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) to build a "universal APK" (see flag `--mode=universal`). You'll have a single APK that you can then share to your clients. Note that you will to ensure that the dynamic features are [configured](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/play-feature-delivery#feature-module-manifest) with "fusing=true" so that they're compiled in the universal APK. Note that this means that these modules will not be downloaded since they're already in the APK.

If you care about your clients seeing and testing the download flow, you'll need to use the [**internal app sharing**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en-GB) feature, or an [**internal test track**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB).

Comment: Thank you Pierre, I've tried the Internal app sharing but it is awkward at best. It forces you to specify a lot of details, images, comments and a lot of other stuf that at the moment I don't even really know yet.... we are speaking about pre-alpha testing, I have no time to lose to add useless details in this phase...

Comment: Hopefully bundletool can help you then.